# How to write functional tests, to drive Selenium using Robot Framework

Tags: windows-7, selenium, python-2.7, robotframework

I have installed python2.7.3 and robotframework2.7.7 on Windows7. Now I want to write some example test cases and execute them with Robot Framework by using Selenium.

How can I do that?

Comment: have you read the user guide? Have you worked through a tutorial?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Download "robotframework-seleniumlibrary-2.9.1.win32.exe" and install it
2. Download "robotframework-seleniumlibrary-demo-20110131.zip" and unzip it
3. Open a command prompt and go to the unzipped folder location (at step 2)
4. Execute the following command to run all tests in a directory:
   rundemo.py login_tests
5. Open report.html to view the result

Download link is  https://code.google.com/p/robotframework-seleniumlibrary/downloads/list